# How did they do it: Trine 2.5d terrain?

Tags: procedural-generation, terrain, terrain-rendering

How did they make the terrain in [trine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl0peCOGh7A#t=00m49s)? I think they took a polygon approach. It doesn't seem that they used a heightmap because it is in all three vectors, or a voxel method because it doesn't have overhangs and cliffs. If it is polygon-based (I assume it is), how in the world would you texture the whole thing?

[image: Terrain]

Notice how it's not very symmetrical and has lots of depth:

[image: Terrain2]

Comment: I removed the `how-its-made` tag because it's a meta tag, and those aren't useful/allowed anymore: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @Tetrad, ok, Tetrad

Comment: They built a polygon landscape and used a bunch of textures and props, just like in any other game. What's so special about Trine's approach that has you intrigued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the same models again and again in Trine. They use a lot of batched rendering. Because of their unique camera angle, a lot of the meshes get culled with frustum culling.

The levels are hand-made by artist. They are just very good at re-using the same models over and over again.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like any regular 3D model.  The only thing that's "2.5D" about it is the fixed camera and play space.

Comment: Ok.... but how would you texture and cull something that large?

Comment: It's probably just broken into chunks.  Maybe some terrain style texture blending on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

The terrain is built as separate meshes by the artist, and possibly have a separate level designer to place the meshes for making the levels. They are just so well-modeled to give the impression that it's one continuous terrain.

In some respects it's really a 2D puzzle action game, making the design and programming of the game logic easier than fully 3D games. The level designer is restricted to just placing the objects along a 2D plane.